# How to send PDF Files to user after Shopping

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on an pdf shopping website.I have implemented the shopping , payment confirmation  and other related things. My question is about "how to send shopped files to users".

I am thinking about following ways to send these files to user but wanted to know the standard way among these all. Please help

1) Creating and sending a zip file as attachment of all pdfs or each as different attachment and send  ( will the high file size effect the email system ???? )

2) Giving the download urls from the server to user. This way arises following things in my mind.

a) If I send a download url to user then user can send it to differnt users. This can be problem

b) If I restrict the user with a token to download it once then in case of internet access problem of other , user can not get the file.

Please suggest a standard way

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store PDF files in a directory above your `www` or `htdocs` or `public_html` (above your web root). It's also possible to store in a web directory, but you need to restrict access with Apache;s Access Control)
2. When a user finishes shopping and you want to send him a file, create a temporary key (`sha1(microtime().session_id()`) and store it along with the purchased file's ID or path on the server in table called `purchases` for example (make sure you have a Boolean column called `key_used` .
3. Send the user a link to `download.php?key=GENERATED_KEY`.
4. download.php will be something like this:

   //look in the purchases table for that key (check if it's not used) and get the file's path
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path_to_pdf));
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');
   readfile($path_to_pdf);
   //change the value of key_used to TRUE

edit: I'm not sure why the code highlight isn't working

Comment: Thank you Adnan. Only one question. This will restrict the user to download it only once. Right ??